# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'xyz' between objects in different contexts

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using Apple's `CoreDataBooks` sample application as a basis for pulling data into a secondary managed object context in the background, and then merging that data into the primary managed object context.

The data I am pulling in is a `Book` entity with a to-one relationship with an `Owner` entity (called "owner"). The `Owner` entity has a to-many relationship with the `Book` (called "books").

My data is an XML document of the form:

```
<Owner>
  <Name>alexpreynolds</Name>
  <ID>123456</ID>
</Owner>
<Books>
  <Book>Book One</Book>
  <Book>Book Two</Book>
  ...   
  <Book>Book N</Book>
</Books>
```

`Book One` through `Book N` are associated with one `Owner` (`"alexpreynolds, 123456"`).

I am parsing this into an `Owner` instance and an `NSMutableSet` made up of `Book` instances.

When I attempt to save the first time, it saves fine and the merged data shows up in the table view.

On the second save, however, when the XML content contains a new book, it doesn't work.

Here's what happens:

I then attempt to load in an XML document that contains a new `Book` not already in the primary managed object context. The new `Book` is using the same `Owner` as that which is associated with the other `Book`s.

I have routines that pick out this unique `Owner` managed object (which I already have in my primary managed object context) and the unique `Book` that is *not* found in the primary MOC.

From this, I create a new `Book` object in the secondary MOC, and I set its "`owner`" relationship to point to the unique `Owner` I found in the primary MOC.

When I save, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a 
relationship 'owner' between objects in 
different contexts 

(source = <Book: 0x7803590> 
(entity: Book; id: 0x7802ae0 <x-coredata:///
Book/t527F06B2-3EB5-47CF-9A29-985B0D3758862>
; data: {
creationDate = 2009-10-12 06:01:53 -0700;
name = nil;
nameInitial = nil;
operations = (
);
owner = nil;
type = 0;
}) , 

destination = <Owner: 0x78020a0> (entity: 
Owner; id: 0x3a56f80 <x-coredata://043AF2F0-1AD0-
4078-A5E8-E9D7071D67D1/Owner/p1> ; data: {
books = "<relationship fault: 0x7801bf0 'books'>";
displayName = alexpreynolds;
ownerID = 123456;
}))'
```

How do I create a new `Book` entity in the secondary MOC, so that I can still associate it with a pre-existing `Owner` in the primary MOC?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can't have relationships between objects in different managed object contexts. So one way of getting around that is to bring the object into the managed object context.

For example:

```
NSManagedObject *book = // get a book in one MOC
NSManagedObject *owner = // get an owner in a different MOC
[[owner mutableSetValueForKey:@"books"] addObject:[owner.managedObjectContext objectWithID:[book objectID]]];
```

So what you're doing is actually fetching the `Book` into the same managed object context with `owner`. Keep in mind, though, that this is only possible if `book` has already been saved. The managed object context is going to look for the object in the persistent store, so it has to be saved first.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was working with Core Data in a background GCD thread, so had to have a background NSManagedObject, which I had forgotten to use to insert the parent object, so it was using the main thread NSManagedObject! Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and this sentence helped me to solve the error.

> You can't have relationships between objects in different managed
>   object contexts. So one way of getting around that is to bring the
>   object into the managed object context.

Here's my code (I replaced the variables to make it work for you):

```
// Have the owner object and get the managedObjectContext
Owner *owner = [[DataFunctions alloc] getCurrentOwner];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [owner managedObjectContext]; 

// Create a book and use the manageObjectContext of owner
Book *book = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newQuote setValue: "Book Title" forKey:@"title"];
[newQuote setOwner:owner];
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Here, you are trying to establish a relation between two objects which are fetched/created with a different context. Core data won't allow you to establish such relations. To achieve this, you should fetch the second object (you are trying to make a relationship with) with the context of the first object with objectID.  Now you should be able to establish a relation between these two objects. For example:

```
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({[unowned self] (localContext: NSManagedObjectContext!) in

    let user = User.MR_createEntityInContext(localContext)!
    .....
    .....
}) //here local context stores data on end of block itself

MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({[unowned self] (localContext: NSManagedObjectContext!) in

    let address = Address.MR_createEntityInContext(localContext)!
    .....
    .....
    let user = localContext.objectWithID(self.user!.objectID) as! User
    user.address = address
})
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you're not allowed to have a relationship in one Core Data object whose value is set to another object held in a different context. One way you can get around this is to wait until after you save the new object and merge it back into the primary context, then set the `owner` relationship as appropriate (since both objects are now in the same context, there's no problem with that).

Comment: Following the Core Data Books example, the secondary MOC is released after the merge occurs. If I instead make the secondary MOC an instance variable, the primary MOC's owner is referring to books in the secondary MOC, which gives the error message. If I have a secondary MOC-owner that refers to books in the secondary MOC, when I merge I now have duplicate owner instances, which is not correct. Ideally I would be able to associate with an existing owner. If you have time, could you please explain your answer in a little more detail?

Answer (score 1):

```
book *book = [mainContext ........]   //Get book from default context

NSManagedObjectID *objectId = [book objectID];

Book *tmpBook = [tmpContext objectWithID:objectId]; //Now book has the legal relationship
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift version...

```
context.insert(objectFromOtherContext)
```