# How to share an entity between two different core data models

Tags: iphone, core-data, model, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm wondering how to share an entity between two different core data models?

For example, I have a "**Universe**" model which describes a "**WorldData**" with its "**CountryData**". And in another hand, I have a "Population" model which describes a "**HumanData**" with its "**CountryData**".

I definitely want to keep my models separated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Core Data Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1)? Managing relationships between entities is pretty basic.

If you want to manage a relationship between your **Universe** entities and your **Population** entities, you should describe them in the same model. Off the top of my head, I can't think of any benefits of putting two related entities in different Core Data Models.

Comment: I know, that's what I've done but now I'm asked to splited the two main functionalities (Universe and Population) so I can produce an independent library corresponding to only one model. That's ok if you consider only the library but I want to reuse this analysis for my own project which include the two models. I want to access to the entity of a model 2 in a model 1 without redefining it...

Comment: I found that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554623/illegal-attempt-to-establish-a-relationship-xyz-between-objects-in-different-co