# Create separate xcdatamodel file for Core Data and merge them on runtime

Tags: ios, core-data, architecture

I have a project separated in one main-project and sub-projects.

I have some abstract entities in the Core Data Model file in the main-project and I would create entities which inherit of the abstract entities into each sub-projects in other Core Data Model file.

Then, when I run the app, I would merge all the Core Data Model files in one.

Do you know if it's possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you mean you want to merge different coredata model entity?

Comment: Yes, I would have entities with relationships between them separated in two .xcdatamodelId files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520300/how-to-share-an-entity-between-two-different-core-data-models