# Managing relationship when seeding data to iCloud store from a local persistent store

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I am trying to seed existing data from a local store to iCloud enabled store. When I try to access a relationship object from local managed object,  the following exception is thrown,

```
> illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in
> different contexts
```

This is what I am trying to do..

```
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [recurringExpense entity];
   RecurringExpense *newRecExpense = [[RecurringExpense alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
   newRecExpense.category = recurringExpense.category;
   [moc assignObject:newRecExpense toPersistentStore:store];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the `category` object created? The error message suggests that it belongs to a different context.

Comment: 'recurringExpense' is from different context.
P.S. 
I changed my plan and going to use [https://github.com/alekseyn/iCloudStoreManager](https://github.com/alekseyn/iCloudStoreManager) to handle seeding and managing stores.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a problem that results from creating relationships outside the managed object context of one of the objects, or across a thread/queue boundary.

According to Apple documentation, "You must create the managed context on the thread on which it will be used." Additionally, the objects on both sides of a relationship need to be referenced in the same NSManagedObjectContext.

From Apple:

See Core Data concurrency here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

The following Stack Overflow answer provides further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554935/1294009